# Raspi z power consumption without monitor

Tags: pi-zero-w, power-management, raspberry-pi-os-bullseye

I run a raspiZW Rev 1.1 with bulleseye lite, headless via ssh. It only waits for a PIR-event to take a video sequence.
Connecting nothing but the camera (B, Rev 2.0) it consumes 110 to 160 mA. Additionally connecting a monitor showing the terminal messages the power consumption is only from 80 to 110 mA. It is not a great difference, but not in the expected direction
I tried to turn off the HDMI with

```
vcgencmd display_power 0
```

with no effect.
Is there a setting where I can fix that?